# XSLT Math Help - Inside of 'XSL:value-of select' Statement

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am having trouble getting the math to work inside of my XSLT. Here is the snippet of code:

```xml
$<xsl:value-of select="(((sum(LOOPSAC[SAC/SAC01='C']/SAC/SAC05)-sum(LOOPSAC[SAC/SAC01='A']/SAC/SAC05)) div 100) +sum(LOOPIT1/TXI/TXI02))"/>
```

I need to sum all of the SAC05 values, deduct the SAC05 values when SAC01 = A, then divide this total by 100. I then need to add the TXI02 values (these don't need to be divided by 100).

The above code is not including the TXI02 value in the total for some reason. It is calculating the first part just fine.

Thanks!
Matt

Here is a sample XML file showing what I'm working with. The above code is what is being used to calculate a "Subtotal" field.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Document810>
    <HEADER>
        <ST>
            <Version>4010</Version>
            <Interchange FunctionalIdentifier="IN" InterchangeDate="230907" ReceiverID="TEST" SenderID="TEST"> </Interchange>
            <ST01>810</ST01>
            <ST02>0012</ST02>
        </ST>
        <BIG>
            <BIG01>20230906</BIG01>
            <BIG02>123456</BIG02>
            <BIG03> </BIG03>
            <BIG04> </BIG04>
            <BIG05> </BIG05>
            <BIG06> </BIG06>
            <BIG07>PR</BIG07>
            <BIG08>00</BIG08>
        </BIG>
        <REF>
            <REF01>12</REF01>
            <REF02>123456</REF02>
            <REF03>BILLING ACCOUNT NUMBER</REF03>
        </REF>
        <LOOPN1>
            <N1>
                <N101>RE</N101>
                <N102>TEST ENERGY</N102>
                <N103>1</N103>
                <N104>006915953</N104>
                <N105> </N105>
                <N106>41</N106>
            </N1>
            <N3>
                <N301>ADDRESS FIELD</N301>
            </N3>
            <N4>
                <N401>MINNEAPOLIS</N401>
                <N402>MN</N402>
                <N403>554849477</N403>
            </N4>
            <PER>
                <PER01>IC</PER01>
                <PER02> </PER02>
                <PER03>TE</PER03>
                <PER04>8004814700</PER04>
            </PER>
        </LOOPN1>
        <LOOPN1>
            <N1>
                <N101>BT</N101>
                <N102>TEST ADDRESS</N102>
                <N103>ZZ</N103>
                <N104>TEST</N104>
                <N105> </N105>
                <N106>40</N106>
            </N1>
            <N3>
                <N301>123456 MAIN ST</N301>
            </N3>
            <N4>
                <N401>DENVER</N401>
                <N402>CO</N402>
                <N403>802042305</N403>
            </N4>
            <PER>
                <PER01>IC</PER01>
                <PER02>JOE SMITH</PER02>
                <PER03>TE</PER03>
                <PER04>3037579567</PER04>
            </PER>
            <ITD>
                <ITD01> </ITD01>
                <ITD02> </ITD02>
                <ITD03> </ITD03>
                <ITD04> </ITD04>
                <ITD05> </ITD05>
                <ITD06>20230926</ITD06>
            </ITD>
            <BAL>
                <BAL01>P</BAL01>
                <BAL02>PB</BAL02>
                <BAL03>64.87</BAL03>
            </BAL>
            <BAL>
                <BAL01>P</BAL01>
                <BAL02>TP</BAL02>
                <BAL03>64.87</BAL03>
            </BAL>
            <BAL>
                <BAL01>M</BAL01>
                <BAL02>J9</BAL02>
                <BAL03>0</BAL03>
            </BAL>
            <BAL>
                <BAL01>M</BAL01>
                <BAL02>PB</BAL02>
                <BAL03>78.66</BAL03>
            </BAL>
            <BAL>
                <BAL01>M</BAL01>
                <BAL02>YB</BAL02>
                <BAL03>78.66</BAL03>
            </BAL>
        </LOOPN1>
    </HEADER>
    <DETAIL>
        <LOOPIT1>
            <IT1>
                <IT101>000001</IT101>
                <IT102> </IT102>
                <IT103> </IT103>
                <IT104> </IT104>
                <IT105> </IT105>
                <IT106>SV</IT106>
                <IT107>ELECTRIC</IT107>
                <IT108>C3</IT108>
                <IT109>METER</IT109>
            </IT1>
            <TXI>
                <TXI01>OH</TXI01>
                <TXI02>0.75</TXI02>
                <TXI03> </TXI03>
                <TXI04> </TXI04>
                <TXI05> </TXI05>
                <TXI06> </TXI06>
                <TXI07> </TXI07>
                <TXI08> </TXI08>
                <TXI09> </TXI09>
                <TXI10>Energy Assistance Ch</TXI10>
            </TXI>
            <MEA>
                <MEA01>AA</MEA01>
                <MEA02>MU</MEA02>
                <MEA03>1</MEA03>
                <MEA04>KH</MEA04>
                <MEA05>39566</MEA05>
                <MEA06>40029</MEA06>
                <MEA07>51</MEA07>
            </MEA>
            <LOOPPID>
                <PID>
                    <PID01>F</PID01>
                    <PID02> </PID02>
                    <PID03> </PID03>
                    <PID04> </PID04>
                    <PID05>ENERGY SERVICE</PID05>
                </PID>
                <REF>
                    <REF01>LU</REF01>
                    <REF02>304604770</REF02>
                    <REF03>PREMISE ACCOUNT NUMBER</REF03>
                </REF>
                <REF>
                    <REF01>MG</REF01>
                    <REF02>000081951065</REF02>
                    <REF03>METER NUMBER</REF03>
                </REF>
                <REF>
                    <REF01>NH</REF01>
                    <REF02>C</REF02>
                    <REF03>COMMERCIAL SERVICE</REF03>
                </REF>
                <DTM>
                    <DTM01>150</DTM01>
                    <DTM02>20230804</DTM02>
                </DTM>
                <DTM>
                    <DTM01>151</DTM01>
                    <DTM02>20230905</DTM02>
                </DTM>
            </LOOPPID>
            <LOOPSLN>
                <SLN>
                    <SLN01>000001</SLN01>
                    <SLN02> </SLN02>
                    <SLN03>A</SLN03>
                </SLN>
            </LOOPSLN>
            <LOOPSAC>
                <SAC>
                    <SAC01>N</SAC01>
                    <SAC02> </SAC02>
                    <SAC03>EU</SAC03>
                    <SAC04>ENC001</SAC04>
                    <SAC05> </SAC05>
                    <SAC06> </SAC06>
                    <SAC07> </SAC07>
                    <SAC08> </SAC08>
                    <SAC09>KH</SAC09>
                    <SAC10>463</SAC10>
                    <SAC11> </SAC11>
                    <SAC12> </SAC12>
                    <SAC13> </SAC13>
                    <SAC14> </SAC14>
                    <SAC15>TOTAL ENERGY</SAC15>
                </SAC>
            </LOOPSAC>
            <LOOPSLN>
                <SLN>
                    <SLN01>000002</SLN01>
                    <SLN02> </SLN02>
                    <SLN03>A</SLN03>
                </SLN>
            </LOOPSLN>
            <LOOPSAC>
                <SAC>
                    <SAC01>C</SAC01>
                    <SAC02> </SAC02>
                    <SAC03>EU</SAC03>
                    <SAC04>ENC001</SAC04>
                    <SAC05>4098</SAC05>
                    <SAC06> </SAC06>
                    <SAC07> </SAC07>
                    <SAC08>0.08852</SAC08>
                    <SAC09>KH</SAC09>
                    <SAC10>463</SAC10>
                    <SAC11> </SAC11>
                    <SAC12> </SAC12>
                    <SAC13> </SAC13>
                    <SAC14> </SAC14>
                    <SAC15>COMMERCIAL SERVICE</SAC15>
                </SAC>
            </LOOPSAC>
            <LOOPSLN>
                <SLN>
                    <SLN01>000003</SLN01>
                    <SLN02> </SLN02>
                    <SLN03>A</SLN03>
                </SLN>
            </LOOPSLN>
            <LOOPSAC>
                <SAC>
                    <SAC01>C</SAC01>
                    <SAC02> </SAC02>
                    <SAC03>EU</SAC03>
                    <SAC04>FFR001</SAC04>
                    <SAC05>1168</SAC05>
                    <SAC06> </SAC06>
                    <SAC07> </SAC07>
                    <SAC08>5.84</SAC08>
                    <SAC09>EA</SAC09>
                    <SAC10>2</SAC10>
                    <SAC11> </SAC11>
                    <SAC12> </SAC12>
                    <SAC13> </SAC13>
                    <SAC14> </SAC14>
                    <SAC15>SERVICE AND FACILITY</SAC15>
                </SAC>
            </LOOPSAC>
            <LOOPSLN>
                <SLN>
                    <SLN01>000004</SLN01>
                    <SLN02> </SLN02>
                    <SLN03>A</SLN03>
                </SLN>
            </LOOPSLN>
            <LOOPSAC>
                <SAC>
                    <SAC01>C</SAC01>
                    <SAC02> </SAC02>
                    <SAC03>EU</SAC03>
                    <SAC04>ADJ002</SAC04>
                    <SAC05>40</SAC05>
                    <SAC06> </SAC06>
                    <SAC07> </SAC07>
                    <SAC08>0.00086</SAC08>
                    <SAC09>KH</SAC09>
                    <SAC10>463</SAC10>
                    <SAC11> </SAC11>
                    <SAC12> </SAC12>
                    <SAC13> </SAC13>
                    <SAC14> </SAC14>
                    <SAC15>TRANS COST ADJ</SAC15>
                </SAC>
            </LOOPSAC>
            <LOOPSLN>
                <SLN>
                    <SLN01>000005</SLN01>
                    <SLN02> </SLN02>
                    <SLN03>A</SLN03>
                </SLN>
            </LOOPSLN>
            <LOOPSAC>
                <SAC>
                    <SAC01>C</SAC01>
                    <SAC02> </SAC02>
                    <SAC03>EU</SAC03>
                    <SAC04>ADJ002</SAC04>
                    <SAC05>1369</SAC05>
                    <SAC06> </SAC06>
                    <SAC07> </SAC07>
                    <SAC08>0.02956</SAC08>
                    <SAC09>KH</SAC09>
                    <SAC10>463</SAC10>
                    <SAC11> </SAC11>
                    <SAC12> </SAC12>
                    <SAC13> </SAC13>
                    <SAC14> </SAC14>
                    <SAC15>ELEC COMMODITY ADJ</SAC15>
                </SAC>
            </LOOPSAC>
            <LOOPSLN>
                <SLN>
                    <SLN01>000006</SLN01>
                    <SLN02> </SLN02>
                    <SLN03>A</SLN03>
                </SLN>
            </LOOPSLN>
            <LOOPSAC>
                <SAC>
                    <SAC01>C</SAC01>
                    <SAC02> </SAC02>
                    <SAC03>EU</SAC03>
                    <SAC04>ADJ002</SAC04>
                    <SAC05>86</SAC05>
                    <SAC06> </SAC06>
                    <SAC07> </SAC07>
                    <SAC08>0.00186</SAC08>
                    <SAC09>KH</SAC09>
                    <SAC10>463</SAC10>
                    <SAC11> </SAC11>
                    <SAC12> </SAC12>
                    <SAC13> </SAC13>
                    <SAC14> </SAC14>
                    <SAC15>DEMAND SIDE MGMT COST</SAC15>
                </SAC>
            </LOOPSAC>
            <LOOPSLN>
                <SLN>
                    <SLN01>000007</SLN01>
                    <SLN02> </SLN02>
                    <SLN03>A</SLN03>
                </SLN>
            </LOOPSLN>
            <LOOPSAC>
                <SAC>
                    <SAC01>C</SAC01>
                    <SAC02> </SAC02>
                    <SAC03>EU</SAC03>
                    <SAC04>ADJ002</SAC04>
                    <SAC05>188</SAC05>
                    <SAC06> </SAC06>
                    <SAC07> </SAC07>
                    <SAC08>0.00406</SAC08>
                    <SAC09>KH</SAC09>
                    <SAC10>463</SAC10>
                    <SAC11> </SAC11>
                    <SAC12> </SAC12>
                    <SAC13> </SAC13>
                    <SAC14> </SAC14>
                    <SAC15>PURCH CAP COST ADJ</SAC15>
                </SAC>
            </LOOPSAC>
            <LOOPSLN>
                <SLN>
                    <SLN01>000008</SLN01>
                    <SLN02> </SLN02>
                    <SLN03>A</SLN03>
                </SLN>
            </LOOPSLN>
            <LOOPSAC>
                <SAC>
                    <SAC01>C</SAC01>
                    <SAC02> </SAC02>
                    <SAC03>EU</SAC03>
                    <SAC04>FFR001</SAC04>
                    <SAC05>73</SAC05>
                    <SAC06> </SAC06>
                    <SAC07> </SAC07>
                    <SAC08>0.009818</SAC08>
                    <SAC09>EA</SAC09>
                    <SAC10>74.35</SAC10>
                    <SAC11> </SAC11>
                    <SAC12> </SAC12>
                    <SAC13> </SAC13>
                    <SAC14> </SAC14>
                    <SAC15>RENEW. ENERGY STD ADJ</SAC15>
                </SAC>
            </LOOPSAC>
            <LOOPSLN>
                <SLN>
                    <SLN01>000009</SLN01>
                    <SLN02> </SLN02>
                    <SLN03>A</SLN03>
                </SLN>
            </LOOPSLN>
            <LOOPSAC>
                <SAC>
                    <SAC01>C</SAC01>
                    <SAC02> </SAC02>
                    <SAC03>EU</SAC03>
                    <SAC04>ADJ002</SAC04>
                    <SAC05>73</SAC05>
                    <SAC06> </SAC06>
                    <SAC07> </SAC07>
                    <SAC08>0.009818</SAC08>
                    <SAC09>KH</SAC09>
                    <SAC10>74.35</SAC10>
                    <SAC11> </SAC11>
                    <SAC12> </SAC12>
                    <SAC13> </SAC13>
                    <SAC14> </SAC14>
                    <SAC15>COLO ENERGY PLAN ADJ</SAC15>
                </SAC>
            </LOOPSAC>
            <LOOPSLN>
                <SLN>
                    <SLN01>000010</SLN01>
                    <SLN02> </SLN02>
                    <SLN03>A</SLN03>
                </SLN>
            </LOOPSLN>
            <LOOPSAC>
                <SAC>
                    <SAC01>C</SAC01>
                    <SAC02> </SAC02>
                    <SAC03>EU</SAC03>
                    <SAC04>ADJ002</SAC04>
                    <SAC05>542</SAC05>
                    <SAC06> </SAC06>
                    <SAC07> </SAC07>
                    <SAC08>0.0117</SAC08>
                    <SAC09>KH</SAC09>
                    <SAC10>463</SAC10>
                    <SAC11> </SAC11>
                    <SAC12> </SAC12>
                    <SAC13> </SAC13>
                    <SAC14> </SAC14>
                    <SAC15>GRSA E</SAC15>
                </SAC>
            </LOOPSAC>
            <LOOPSLN>
                <SLN>
                    <SLN01>000011</SLN01>
                    <SLN02> </SLN02>
                    <SLN03>A</SLN03>
                </SLN>
            </LOOPSLN>
            <LOOPSAC>
                <SAC>
                    <SAC01>C</SAC01>
                    <SAC02> </SAC02>
                    <SAC03>EU</SAC03>
                    <SAC04>ADJ002</SAC04>
                    <SAC05>5</SAC05>
                    <SAC06> </SAC06>
                    <SAC07> </SAC07>
                    <SAC08>0.0001</SAC08>
                    <SAC09>KH</SAC09>
                    <SAC10>463</SAC10>
                    <SAC11> </SAC11>
                    <SAC12> </SAC12>
                    <SAC13> </SAC13>
                    <SAC14> </SAC14>
                    <SAC15>TRANS ELEC PLAN</SAC15>
                </SAC>
            </LOOPSAC>
            <LOOPSLN>
                <SLN>
                    <SLN01>000012</SLN01>
                    <SLN02> </SLN02>
                    <SLN03>A</SLN03>
                </SLN>
            </LOOPSLN>
            <LOOPSAC>
                <SAC>
                    <SAC01>C</SAC01>
                    <SAC02> </SAC02>
                    <SAC03>EU</SAC03>
                    <SAC04>ADJ002</SAC04>
                    <SAC05>61</SAC05>
                    <SAC06> </SAC06>
                    <SAC07> </SAC07>
                    <SAC08>0.00131</SAC08>
                    <SAC09>KH</SAC09>
                    <SAC10>463</SAC10>
                    <SAC11> </SAC11>
                    <SAC12> </SAC12>
                    <SAC13> </SAC13>
                    <SAC14> </SAC14>
                    <SAC15>RDA</SAC15>
                </SAC>
            </LOOPSAC>
            <LOOPSLN>
                <SLN>
                    <SLN01>000013</SLN01>
                    <SLN02> </SLN02>
                    <SLN03>A</SLN03>
                </SLN>
            </LOOPSLN>
            <LOOPSAC>
                <SAC>
                    <SAC01>C</SAC01>
                    <SAC02> </SAC02>
                    <SAC03>EU</SAC03>
                    <SAC04>ADJ002</SAC04>
                    <SAC05>210</SAC05>
                    <SAC06> </SAC06>
                    <SAC07> </SAC07>
                    <SAC08>0.00453</SAC08>
                    <SAC09>KH</SAC09>
                    <SAC10>463</SAC10>
                    <SAC11> </SAC11>
                    <SAC12> </SAC12>
                    <SAC13> </SAC13>
                    <SAC14> </SAC14>
                    <SAC15>EGCRR</SAC15>
                </SAC>
            </LOOPSAC>
            <LOOPN1>
                <N1>
                    <N101>MQ</N101>
                    <N102>CDOT R1430010</N102>
                </N1>
                <N3>
                    <N301>6019 W 52ND AVE</N301>
                </N3>
                <N4>
                    <N401>ARVADA</N401>
                    <N402>CO</N402>
                    <N403>80002</N403>
                </N4>
            </LOOPN1>
        </LOOPIT1>
    </DETAIL>
    <SUMMARY>
        <TDS>
            <TDS01>7866</TDS01>
        </TDS>
        <CTT>
            <CTT01>1</CTT01>
        </CTT>
        <SE>
            <SE01>58</SE01>
            <SE02>0012</SE02>
        </SE>
    </SUMMARY>
</Document810>
```

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Well-formed input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT stylesheet that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.

Comment: Added sample XML file above. I can add the entire XSLT if needed but really just need help with this one calculation as the rest is working fine. To be clear, I am getting a value, it's just not adding the TXI02 value for some reason.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide (1) a well-formed XML input, reduced to the minimum required to demonstrate the problem, (2) a full, executable XSLT, also reduced to minimum and (3) the exact result you expect to get - see: [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAICT, `LOOPSAC` is a child of `LOOPIT1`.

You are not showing the context of your calculation, but if the expression:

```
sum(LOOPSAC[SAC/SAC01='C']/SAC/SAC05)
```

works, then you must be in the context of `LOOPIT1`.

Now, `TX1` is also a child of `LOOPIT1`. So if you are already in the context of `LOOPIT1`, the expression:

```
sum(LOOPIT1/TXI/TXI02)
```

will return 0, because `LOOPIT1` is not a child of itself and no nodes are being selected by this path. It needs to be:

```
sum(TXI/TXI02)
```

---

You could have deduced all this by yourself if you had started by isolating the expression:

```
count(LOOPIT1/TXI/TXI02)
```

and continued from there.